# Float64MultiArray message type does not show up in published topic

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to do a test where I publish an array to a topic
`/chatter2s`. Here is my publisher below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Float64MultiArray
#Float64MultiArray


def do_it():
    data_to_send = Float64MultiArray()
    rospy.init_node("array_publisher")
    pub=rospy.Publisher("chatters2", Float64MultiArray, queue_size=10)

    data_to_send.data = [1.2354567, 99.7890]
    #ata_to_send.data_offset = 0
    pub.publish(data_to_send)
    rospy.spin()

do_it()
```

Here is my listener:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Float64MultiArray


def callback(msg):
    rospy.loginfo(msg)

rospy.init_node("array_listener")
rospy.Subscriber("chatters2",Float64MultiArray, callback)
#rospy.sleep(3.0)
rospy.spin()
```

The problem is, when I run these two codes in their respective terminals, they seem to run but then nothing shows up for the listener, I do a `rostopic echo /chatters2` and dont see anything coming out for that either.
I check the `rqt_graph` and I see  both nodes as well as the chatter topic, so these nodes seem to be active. whats going on?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/395724/float64multiarray-message-type-does-not-show-up-in-published-topic/) by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2022-02-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `rospy.spin()` in your listener is waiting for a callback to be executed. By writing that line, you are essentially asking ROS to handle that for you. In your publisher, you don't want to wait for callbacks. So you need to omit the spin. You will also need a loop to continually publish your data. From the [ROS simple publisher tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers) your example would look like this:

```
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Float64MultiArray
#Float64MultiArray


def do_it():
    data_to_send = Float64MultiArray()
    rospy.init_node("array_publisher")
    pub=rospy.Publisher("chatters2", Float64MultiArray, queue_size=10)
    
    data_to_send.data = [1.2354567, 99.7890]
    #ata_to_send.data_offset = 0

    r = rospy.Rate(10) # 10hz
    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
      pub.publish(data_to_send)
      # rospy.spin()
      r.sleep()

do_it()
```

---

Originally posted by [Akhil Kurup](https://answers.ros.org/users/63962/akhil-kurup/) with karma: 459 on 2022-02-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Akhil Kurup](https://answers.ros.org/users/63962/akhil-kurup/) on 2022-02-06**:
Also, since you mention ROS-melodic, you may want to change the python3 to python2

**Comment by [distro](https://answers.ros.org/users/75936/distro/) on 2022-02-08**:
@Akhil Kurup Thanks! Could you please look at a related question I asked [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/395870/publisher-and-subscriber-nodes-dont-seem-to-be-communicating/) if possible.